# Radio button selection should not be changed by any one

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have made a radio button list in an aspx page in C#

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RblMentor_teacher_student" class="case"  runat="server"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AppendDataBoundItems="False" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Docent" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Mentor" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Student" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

It works perfectly as I want that it shows the selected person is either teacher or student or mentor.

But I want that no one can change the selection of this.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put this in your `Page_load()` and it would disable the whole list.

```
RblMentor_teacher_student.Enabled = false;
```

Or you could disable a specific list item

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Docent" Value="0" Disabled="Disabled"></asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Enabled` property to `false`

Answer (score 1):

On **selectedindexchanged** event of radiobutton..then put enable property false for selected item

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

**Benefit of using this is that the checked value will be always post on submit.**

```
   $(function () {
            $("input[type=radio]", $("#<%= RblMentor_teacher_student.ClientID%>")).each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).attr("checked") != "checked") {
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
   });
```